# how to read Kinect V2 Depth image with matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, 3d, kinect

I have extracted 16-bit floating data maxtix of the depth from kinect V2 .
how could i visual see it ?

I have attached a sample of the matrix as a png file.

im sure it's simple but i didnt found it on web.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have a 16bit gray level range but most of your values are at the lower end.
Therefor everything looks dark.

You can either look at a smaller range of your values that acutally contains the visual info and cutt off the rest or you can alter your data like displaying the log of your data.. Another solution would be using a colour map.
Make sure you understand why you hardly see anything here. Check out the histogram of your data and compare it to the histogram of a well visible image!

Give this stuff a try:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/contrast-adjustment-.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer but non of the functions in the page was not relevant. 
instead i used imagesc function!

Answer (score 0):

I have just used imagesc to visualize my picture